# What changes about the data type of this APL variable with these lines of code?

Tags: apl

I am writing a text file from APL.
I have a character matrix defined as UMMB in my APL script, which is being used for the body of this text file.
I am able to successfully call my .txt document writing function using this variable as the body.

When I do the following, however:

```
k←⊂⍕UMMB
m←⊂'<html><body><table>'
n←⊂'</html></body></table>'
k←m,k,n
```

And I use the variable k as my body instead of UMMB, I get an error every time this function runs. I also tried enclosing k at the end of all the lines above, but to no avail.

What is different about the definition of k as opposed to UMMB that my function doesn't like?

(I don't have the source code or documentation for this function- I'm only able to call it blindly.)

Edit: I attempted Adam's suggestion of using the split function:

```
↓
```

But as it turns out, the program I am using the APL editor in doesn't recognize this as the split function, but instead the 'drop function,' detailed here:

[image]

I cannot seem to find the equivalent of split for this version of APL.

Comment: Can you give the output of `⍴UMMB` (shape a.k.a. dimensions) and `≡UMMB` (depth)? Just one example (that works with the "document writing function" you have) will be enough.

Comment: You can get better answers by mentioning which APL dialect and version you use.

Comment: Where does this documentation page come from? Is there an accompanying title page?

Comment: Not related to your APL question, but it looks like the elements in variable n are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`⍕UMMB` is a simple character matrix, but your final `k` ends up being a 3-element vector of a vector, a matrix, and a vector. You may need to build a single simple character matrix. Since I don't know what APL system you are using, here is a version that should work universally:

```
k←⍕UMMB                     ⍝ simple character matrix where ⍕ may be unnecessary
m←'<html><body><table>'     ⍝ simple character vector
n←'</html></body></table>'  ⍝ simple character vector

w←(1↓⍴k)⌈(⍴m)⌈(⍴n)          ⍝ max width of k and m and n

kw←((1↑⍴k),w)↑k             ⍝ extend k to that width
mw←w↑m                      ⍝ extend m to that width
nw←w↑n                      ⍝ extend n to that width

k←mw,[⍳1]kw,[⍳1]nw          ⍝ stack the three
```

---

<sup>**Side note:** I recommend against re-use of variable names, as it prevents you from going back and inspecting what the original value was.</sup>

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get an incorrect syntax error on the like where k is assigned to UMMB now with the split function. I understand it's monadic, but this error makes it seem like it isn't. Any clue as to why an error would be thrown on that line?

Comment: @JadenRanzenberger Maybe `k` is already a function? Try issuing `)erase k` and then try again.

Comment: @JadenRanzenberger You may also be interesting in visiting [the APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) for chat-based assistance

Comment: No this doesn't seem to be an issue- I used a previously unassigned variable defined in my function to test and it threw the same error.. I am using APL within a different professional software tool so It may be an issue with this specific tool...

Comment: @JadenRanzenberger Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: refer to my updated question: As it turns out, for me that isn't the split function, but instead the drop function. I'm not exactly sure what this version of APL is then, and there seems to be some variation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206370/discussion-between-adam-and-jaden-ranzenberger).

Comment: @JadenRanzenberger I've updated my answer to account for the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to split up the character matrix into a vector of character vectors and then attach the other two at either end. Then you can use Disclose to turn it back into a character matrix:

```
k←⊂[1+⎕IO]⍕UMMB
m←⊂'<html><body><table>'
n←⊂'</table></body></html>'
k←⊃m,k,n
```

(I took the liberty of swapping `table` and `body` in `n`.)